# Mendeley Desktop 1.19.2 doesn't launch in Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: mendeley

Hej there,
I installed the latest version of Mendeley Desktop, but it simply doesn't launch. On the Mendeley HP (https://www.mendeley.com/download-desktop/) I chose the 32bit-version on the right (Download for Ubuntu and Kubuntu 16.04 LTS, 17.04 and Debian Stretch). I'm not very Ubuntu-wise and hopefully I can get some support this way. :)

Comment: You probably installed the 64-bit version of Ubuntu -- have you tried the 64-bit Mendeley?

Comment: No, I'm quite sure I have installed 32-bit version. In this moment I'm trying to install the left 32bit-version on the HP mentioned above, but this is a tar.bz2 folder and I don't know how to "install" it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 does not work with 32 bit anymore. So you have the 64 bit version and you need to chose the 64 bit-version of mendeley

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to install the program and it does not start, use

```
sudo mendeleydesktop
```

instead of

```
mendeleydesktop
```

I have the same issue, and it seems something is not right about the user permissions.